# How to select MAX id and convert Result to int

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to get the MAX id from my table and add a number to it. When the result is stored after executing the query, I save it into another variable and add 1. I get an error: "Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int"

I have tried:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$uniqueCode = $row+1;
```

This is the current code I have to get the maximum reference number:

```
    $sql = "SELECT MAX(referenceNo) FROM taxibookings LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Do a `dump_var($row);` and you will see what adding 1 to it will not work. Same for `$result` of your current code.

Comment: `$result` is a result object. Fetch it; and/or `$row` is an `array`. What are you trying to do? Sounds like you should be using auto incrementing column.

Comment: This is bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using auto increment and want to find the max id then it is simple that find the last entry of the table if there is no deletion of the row because if you are deleting row then its bad way to handle database never delete manage it with status column if its required to delete.See the below code.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
// find last id which will be the max 
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(referenceNo) as referenceNo FROM taxibookings";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$uniqueCode = $data['referenceNo']+1;
```

Comment: Or how to destroy database integrity

Comment: this is the answer